# How to get the return values from gevent Group calls?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gevent

In python I am using `gevent` to make parallel requests. The code without gevent would look like this:

```
for request in requests:
    url = request["url"]
    response = self.get(url)
```

and with `gevent` it looks like this:

```
from gevent.pool import Group
group = Group()
for request in requests:
    url = request["url"]
    group.spawn(lambda: self.get(url))
group.join()
```

Now my question: How do I get the return value from the calls to `self.get`?

Comment: Is there any reason not to use [grequests](https://github.com/spyoungtech/grequests) ?

Comment: No - except the fact that I was unaware of `grequests`. I will take a look, thanks!

Comment: @MauriceMeyer I am not sure how I can use grequests with my code example. Wouldn't a sequence like `rs = (self.get(u) for u in urls)` actually already make the requests?

Comment: No, `grequests.map(rs)` starts the requests. In [map](https://github.com/spyoungtech/grequests/blob/3d0b36016bd33bcef682c2bdbcc907b8c2d81f65/grequests.py#L111), a `Pool` is created and 'joined'